# Regex grouping template with first, middle and end group

Tags: regex

I would like to create a regex with the following requirements.

1. First (single) char unicode letter with including and excluding option (GROUP1)
2. Second (and more) char optional list with including and excluding option (GROUP2)
3. End (single) char unicode letter with including and excluding option (GROUP3)

It should not be permissible for one and the same **not letter** to appear twice in a row, what i ve is this now

```
^(?!.{32})(?:[\p{L}.]*?)(?:[ ,'-][\p{L}.]+)*?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/KmMkIk/1

Comment: It sounds like `^(?!.{136})\p{L}+(?:[ ,.'-]\p{L}+)*$` is what can help.

Comment: Here re some examples https://regex101.com/r/KmMkIk/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure what you mean with your three different groupings, but by your sample data it looks like you could try:

```
^(?!.{136})\p{L}+\.?(?:[ ,'-]?\p{L}+\.?)*$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ueqXiw/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(?!.{136})` - Negative lookahead to avoid a line to have 136 (or more) characters other than newline;
- `\p{L}+\.?` - Any 1+ (Greedy) letter from any language and an optional literal dot;
- `(?:[ ,'-]?\p{L}+\.?)*` - A non-capture group (0+ times) to optionally match any character from the give class and any 1+ letter from any language followed by another optional dot;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

Comment: If this is an engine allowing possessive quantifiers, you would probably like to use them to reduce redundant backtracking, `^(?!.{136})\p{L}++\.?+(?:[ ,'-]?+\p{L}+\.?+)*$`.